# Visualize multiplex network

Tags: r, matrix, visualization, igraph

How can I visualize this as a multiplex network? It currently reads the edges as nodes, and I am unsure of how to add edge color based on weight (i.e. 1,2,3).

```
mat <- read.table(header=FALSE, 
                text=" 
-   -   2   -   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   -
-   -   -   -   -   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   -
2   -   -   -   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1
-   -   -   -   -   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   3   -
2   -   2   -   -   -   1   -   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1
1   1   2   1   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   2   1   2   2   2
1   2   1   2   1   -   -   -   -   -   -   1   2   1   -   2
1   1   1   1   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   2
1   1   1   1   1   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   2
1   1   1   1   1   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   2
1   1   1   1   1   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   2   2
1   1   1   1   1   2   1   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   2
2   2   2   3   2   1   2   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   1
1   1   1   1   1   2   1   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   2
1   1   1   -   1   2   -   -   -   -   2   -   -   -   -   2
-   -   1   -   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   2   2   -
")   

g <- graph_from_data_frame(mat, directed=FALSE)

plot(g)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you intend the table provided above as the adjacency matrix. read.table will give you a data.frame, not a matrix,  so you need to convert it using `as.matrix`.
Also, if you put dashes into the matrix, the whole thing will be interpreted as characters, not numbers.  So I changed your dashes to zeros and then used `graph_from_adjacency_matrix` to get a graph. You can set the edge color in `plot` by specifying the edge.color argument.

```
library(igraph)

mat <- read.table(header=FALSE, 
         text=" 0   0   2   0   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   0
0   0   0   0   0   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   0
2   0   0   0   2   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1
0   0   0   0   0   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   3   0
2   0   2   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1
1   1   2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   1   2   2   2
1   2   1   2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   1   0   2
1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   2
1   1   1   1   1   2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
2   2   2   3   2   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
1   1   1   1   1   2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
1   1   1   0   1   2   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   2
0   0   1   0   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   1   2   2   0") 
mat = as.matrix(mat)  

g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(mat, weighted=TRUE, mode="undirected")

plot(g, edge.color=E(g)$weight)
```

[image: Graph with edges colored by weight]

I think that this is what you were trying to get, but if not,  please try to say more clearly what you hope to get.